# How to change the tag name of the serialized XML element via IXmlSerializable

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Some background:

We have some entity classes need to be serialized, so we implement the entity class as following in the first edition:

```
[XmlType("FooElement")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The serialized XML string should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="gb2312"?>
<FooElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" mlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">foo</FooElement>
```

But we need to make the Text property as read only, so we change the Foo class to implement the IXmlSerializable interface as following:

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo : IXmlSerializable
{
    public Foo()
    { }

    public Foo(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }

    public string Text { get; private set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        Text = reader.Value;
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(Text);
    }
}
```

Then the serialized XML string was also changed as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="gb2312"?><Foo>foo</Foo>
```

Is there any way to change the tag name from "`<Foo>foo</Foo>`" to "`<FooElement>foo</FooElement>`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, [XmlRootAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx) should play well with IXmlSerializable.